# CLang++ generating spurious vars in LLVM_IR

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Please consider the following program:

```
int main() {
    int test = 17;
    return test;
}
```

Compile to LLVM_IR: `clang++ -S -emit-llvm test.cpp`

Looking at the IR, the function main is defined as so:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline norecurse nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  store i32 17, i32* %2, align 4
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  ret i32 %3
}
```

We can see that `%2` is the allocation of our `test` variable, loading `17` into it, and `%3` uses that variable as the funcition's return value (in keep with the code as we wrote it). However, we see that `%1` defines *another* `int` sized variable, and initializes it to 0, despite never using it. This extra variable is nowhere to be seen in the C++ source.

I should note that I see the same being generated when I compile using `clang` rather than `clang++`.

What is this extra variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using an old version of `clang`. In the new version ( I mean v7.0 and later), value names are printed by default. But to be explicitly print, you might you `-fno-discard-value-names`. With this option you'll get the following IR:

```
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %test = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  store i32 17, i32* %test, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %test, align 4
  ret i32 %0
}
```

Now it is quiet clear where `store 0` comes from. In an unoptimized code, the compiler initializes the `retval` to `0`.

Comment: Actually, this is LLVM 7. Thank you for the useful option, however.